# How to find out the control function of a cosine wave?

Tags: geometry, parameter-estimation

I have a system which is sampling at 100Hz. There is only one input for the system. The output is similar to cosine waveforms with varying frequency. I have no clue how to find out the exact formula to put into the cosine function to generate the exact output as the system. Please give me some suggestion. Thanks

Here are some data

When input = 0.1, local max occurs at the following data points

1   3545    5014    6140    7090    7927    8684    9379

When input = 0.2,

1   2507    3545    4342    5014    5605    6140    6632    7090    7520    7927    8314    8684    9038    9379    9709

When input = 0.3,

1   2047    2895    3545    4094    4577    5014    5415    5789    6140    6473    6788    7090    7380    7658    7927    8187    8439    8684    8922    9153    9379    9600    9816

Comment: While this ought to be far too little information to answer the question, it looks like your data points increase in a $\sqrt n$ fashion, which suggests that the function is of the form $\cos(ct^2)$ for some $c$. For example, I get a pretty good fit to your second data set with $\cos(t^2/200)$, where $t$ is in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to compute the square of your values and then the differences between these squares :

> v1=[1, 3545, 5014, 6140, 7090, 7927, 8684, 9379]
>   vector(#v1-1,k,v1[k+1]^2-v1[k]^2)
>   = [12567024, 12573171, 12559404, 12568500, 12569229, 12574527, 12553785]
>       (mean value $m_1=12566520$)
>
> v2=[1, 2507, 3545, 4342, 5014, 5605, 6140, 6632, 7090, 7520, 7927, 8314, 8684, 9038, 9379, 9709] 
>   vector(#v2-1,k,v2[k+1]^2-v2[k]^2)
>   = [6285048, 6281976, 6285939, 6287232, 6275829, 6283575, 6283824, 6284676, 6282300, 6286929, 6285267, 6289260, 6273588, 6280197, 6299040]
>       (mean value $m_2=6284312$)

with $\dfrac{m1}{m_2}=1.99966\cdots$  a rather good approximation of $2$ !

Your function could be given by $f(x)= a\cdot \cos(b\cdot I\cdot x^2)\ $ with $I$ the input and $a$ and $b$ two constants.

Let's find $b$ for $I=0.1$ we must have $2\pi = b\cdot 0.1\cdot 12566520$ so that $b=\dfrac {2\pi\cdot 10}{12566520}\approx 5\cdot 10^{-6}$ and your answer should be near of : $$f(x)= a\cdot \cos\left(5\cdot 10^{-6}\cdot I\cdot x^2\right)$$
(or $\cdots (x-1)^2)$ if you prefer...)

Here is a plot of the result for $I=0.1$ :

[image: plot]